# Encoding URL with Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)

Tags: url, encoding, character-encoding

1. So, I have a payment page, and some data which I have encrypted using AES (part 1) which upon clicks redirect me to receipt page by passing the data in the URL.
2. Then on the receipt page, I am decrypting the AES code.
   Problem is that when "some data" is in the URL, it is in the correct format in order to be decrypted
3. But when I retrieve the "some data", the value changes for example sign '+' and sign '=' is invisible or replace by another character.

Payment page: Passing the data in the URL.

```
  string fn = (txtdonorname.Text.Trim()); // the data
  string redirectUrl = string.Format("../4home/creceipt.aspx?&us={1}",Encryption(us));
  string script = "setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = '" + redirectUrl + "'; }, 4000);";
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RedirectScript", script, true);
```

Receipt page: Retrieving the data in the URL.

```
 https://localhost:44371/farms/creceipt?us=c9Qj2sFpCM9A+s6YbT4nPg==&

 string us = (Request.QueryString["us"]);
 lbluname.Text = ((us));
```

1. It only displays: c9Qj2sFpCM9A s6YbT4nPg== compared to c9Qj2sFpCM9A+s6YbT4nPg==
2. sign "+" is missing which prevent me from decrypting. ONLY SIGN "+"

Comment: https://base64.guru/standards/base64url

Comment: @Martheen I have used "string encodedUs = Request.QueryString["us"];
                string decodedUs = Uri.UnescapeDataString(encodedUs.Replace(" ", "+"));
                lbluname.Text = decodedUs;"

Comment: @Martheen what do you think?

Comment: Nah, just use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.base64urlencoder?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest inside your encryption class. Your solution won't handle `/`, you can't use replace on the receiving end since it would already cut off.